# movingapp to extsd

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I have a 10.1" dragon touch with lollipop, and cannot get around moving apps to ext sd to save space. I can see how it is configured, and your directions to root my device, which i did, but none of my apps want to route the downloads through your extsd in storage, and instead write to the emulated sd space on my internal sd card. I can copy and view photos and videos on my sd card, but several of my applications come with a ton of data which quickly uses up my internal sd. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Not all apps can be moved to sd because of specifications made by the programmer, maybe you need app2sd from google play, i have tested it before with 4.4.4 sucessfully for those apps that can not be moved to sd, root permissions are required.